# Why would Autohotkey script suddenly stop working?

Tags: autohotkey

We have an AutoHotkey script that was working for months or years and has suddenly stopped working this week.  I restored a copy of the script from January and confirmed that it is no longer working either.

We did have some Windows updates applied this week, so I'm assuming something changed in the environment that is impacting the script, but I just cannot figure out what it might be.

The error is, "Error at line 3. Line Text: global stop:= True.  Error: This line does not contain a recognized action.  The program will exit."

This is the top part of the script:

```
esc:: 
; Kill switch, press the escape key to stop a script 
global stop:= True
global stop1:= True
global stop2:= True
global stop3:= True
return

;-----------+
; Functions |
;-----------+
```

I tried changing the stop variable to stop4, just in case "stop" has suddenly become some sort of reserved word, but no luck.

Any thoughts on what might be going wrong here?

Comment: Can you provide the whole script?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.  It wasn't actually anything to do with the global variable.  We just needed to download the latest version of ahk.